# How to cover expected exceptions with dotcover?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dotcover

I'm using Dotcover to see the coverage  that my unittests have of my production code. It works quite well except when I'm trying to test thrown exceptions and that is my question what I'm doing wrongly there. I've tried both variants below already and only get a coverage of 92% or 89%.

As a note on the unit testing framework: I'm using no external/additional framework there but the Unittest framework that comes with Visual studio itself.

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(FormatException), "No exception or exception of wrong type thrown")]
public void TestException()
{
    new myClass().DatabaseID = 0;
}
```

---

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestException()
{
    try {
        new myClass().DatabaseID = 0;
        Assert.Fail
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue (ex is FormatException);
    }
}
```

I've also tried with a formatexception in the catch and another catch around it, but still the highest I get is 92% and else way less down to 16% even. So Like mentioned my question here is what am I doing wrong there?

As additional info about myclass it has the following Property and private variable:

```
private int _DatabaseID;

public int DatabaseID
{
     get { return _DataBaseID; }
     set { if (value != 0) {_DatabaseID = value; } else { throw new FormatException ("haha"); }
}
```

Comment: "I'm using Dotcover to cover my unittests" - why? Coverage is usually used to check that your tests cover all of your production code... what are you hoping to achieve with this? Finding methods which should be tests but which are missing attributes? (As an aside, does whatever test framework you're using not include `Assert.Throws<TException>(Action)` or something similar? That's a generally better approach.)

Comment: As Test framework I'm using the normal Visual studio 2013 unittests (so no external test framework). 

The "cover unittests with dotcover" is straightly taken from the menupoint on right mouseclick^^ (it is as you mentioned how much of the production code is covered by the unit tests)

I'm going to try that one assert and post the result into the question in a few mins.

Comment: hmm the normal unittests from VS don't have assert.throws in VS 2013?

Comment: Just because something is available on a context menu doesn't mean it's a good idea. What are you trying to achieve by looking at the coverage in your unit test project? I'm surprised if MSTest doesn't have Assert.Throws, but it's possible :(

Comment: The wording of that context menu is quite bad. Order here is that I have to achieve 100% coverage where possible. What surprised me there was when the productive code showed 100% while unittests showed 96% (with the tests where exceptions are tested showing only 80 or even worse 16% coverage) and thus I'm looking if it is intrinsic to dotcover or if there is something I did wrong in these regards (from dotcovers pov at least).  For Assert: I tried with Assert.T but autocomplete said nothing that starts with T there in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert

Comment: No, I looked at the docs and couldn't see anything - you might want to switch to another unit test system if you're still in early stages. I question why 100% coverage for unit tests is a goal at all though. In particular, any calls to `Assert.Fail` will clearly *not* be covered if your unit tests pass...